# Xamarin.Forms Asset Catalogue disappeared

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms project that had an Asset Catalogue full of images for my app.
I built the app this morning fine and ran on my test device.
I then changed the LaunchScreen.Storyboard file in my Resources folder (confirmed by source control that this is the only file that changed) and my asset catalogue has disappeared.

I tried adding a new one (in the hope I could re-add the images) but even the new one doesn't show under the dropdown (although it exists in the folder).

I reverted the change via source control and the app still won't build, and I can't figure out how to re-add my asset catalogue.

[image: Error Message when building]
[image: Missing catalogue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. I unloaded my iOS project from the Solution Explorer and opened the .csproj file and commented out "Assets.xcassets/Images.imageset/Contents.json" and reloaded the project